# how to check if cpanel can login successfully with python2.7?

Tags: python, cpanel

i need a script to make it like a cpanel checker, with more than 1 url and the url is stored in a txt file.

usage : `python script.py list.txt`

format in file list.txt : `https://demo.cpanel.net:2083|democom|DemoCoA5620`

this is my code but it doesn't work, can someone help me?

Thanks.

```
import requests, sys
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

try:
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
        list_data = [line.strip() for line in f if line.strip()]
except IOError:
    pass

def cpanel(url):

    try:

        data = {'user':'democom', 'pass':'DemoCoA5620'}

        r = requests.post(url, data=data)

        if r.status_code==200:

            print "login success"

        else:

            print "login failed"

    except:
        pass


def chekers(url):

    try:
        cpanel(url)
    except:
        pass

def Main():
    try:
        start = timer()
        pp = ThreadPool(25)
        pr = pp.map(chekers, list_data)
        print('Time: ' + str(timer() - start) + ' seconds')
    except:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your code in a way that it will return an actual array containing a boolean array indicating the success of the cpanel function.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import requests
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
try:
    list_data = ["https://demo.cpanel.net:2083|democom|DemoCoA5620",
                 "https://demo.cpanel.net:2083|UserDoesNotExist|WRONGPASSWORD",
                 ]
except IOError:
    pass

def cpanel(url):

    try:
        # try to split that url to get username / password

        try:
            url, username, password = url.split('|')
        except Exception as e:
            print("Url {} seems to have wrong format. Concrete error: {}".format(url, e))
            return False

        # build the correct url
        url += '/login/?login_only=1'

        # build post parameters
        params = {'user': username,
                  'pass': password}

        # make request
        r = requests.post(url, params)

        if r.status_code==200:

            print("login for user {} success".format(username))
            return True

        else:

            print("login for user {} failed due to Status Code {} and message \"{}\"".format(username, r.status_code, r.reason))
            return False

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error occured for url {} ".format(e))
        return False


def chekers(url):
    return cpanel(url)


def Main():
    try:
        # start = timer()
        pp = ThreadPool(1)
        pr = pp.map(chekers, list_data)
        print(pr)
        # print('Time: ' + str(timer() - start) + ' seconds')
    except:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Output:

```
login for user democom success
login for user UserDoesNotExist failed due to Status Code 401 and message "Access Denied"
[True, False]
```

Be aware that I replaced your file read operation by some fixed urls.

Since you use `request.post` I guess you actually want to POST something to that urls. Your code does not do that. If you just want to send a request, use the `requests.get` method.

See the official documentation for the requests packet: `https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request` for more details.

Also note that

> "but it doesn't work"

is NOT a question.

Comment: yes, but I need a cpanel login with username and password data to find out if the login is successful, and I use `request.post ()` only for you or someone else to help fix my code for which there is no username and password data.

Comment: here i give you valid login cpanel demo : login : `https://demo.cpanel.net:2083` username : `democom` password : `DemoCoA5620`

Comment: I updated the answer to use your given data. The Login works and responds with 200 for correct data and 401 for incorrect data.

Comment: Glad I could help. Another side node: If you dont have any specific reasons move to Python 3.X, since 2.X is deprecated very soon.